# Create SEO Friendly hyperlinks using IIS Tools

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, iis-7.5

I use Asp.net 4.

I have some code in C# that generates html hyperlinks on a web page, I would like to make this hyperlinks SEO friendly using **URL Rewrite Tool from IIS 7.5**.

Is it possible? Or shall I use URL Routing mechanism instead?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found an answer to my question here:

IIS 7.5 Can Modify the links in the HTML markup generated by a web application behind a reverse proxy.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference/#Tag_Filters